# MariaDB/MySQL Errors - Table & Server Crashes (WHM Server)

Tags: mysql, cpanel, mariadb, whm

I don't know what's going on. My server has been fine for probably a year. Now I'm having a severe problem with MariaDB/MySQL. The DB server keeps crashing. When it does and I bring it back online I get errors, several tables are marked crashed and I have to repair them. Here are the server specs...

```
CloudLinux Server release 6.6 installed on Centos 6.5 (x64)
WHM/Cpanel 11.50.1 Build 1 (Current)
MariaDB 10.0.21
RAM: 3,820MB (3750MB+ in use)
Swap: 1,023MB (1,023MB in use)
4 Cores (Low idle load)
Available Disk Space: 26GB
```

I suspect it has to do with memory. Here's a memory alert I get in WHM:

[image: WHM Memory Alert]

Here's what I get when I try to visit a web site on my server that uses MySQL (As expected):

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Connection refused in /home/mysite/public_html/index.php on line 19
Unable to connect to server.
```

Here's a link to the main error log of my database server (Too much to post here): http://wikisend.com/download/182056/proton.myserver.com.err.txt

This is what happens when I restart my database server from WHM. Each time I restart the db server, random tables are marked as crashed. Sometimes a lot of tables, sometimes just a few and then I have to repair them:

[image: WHM MariaDB/MySQL Errors]

Here is the contents of the /etc/my.cnf file:

```
root@proton [~]# cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=10000
innodb_buffer_pool_size=123731968
```

The only thing I've tried to fix this is setting this option in WHM:

[image: Attempted Fix]

I only have a handful of sites on the server. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';
```

Do you have other products running in the same VM/server?  How much of the 3750MB are they using?  Consider increasing RAM as a quick fix.  Otherwise, lets look for what is chewing up RAM.

You are probably no using any InnoDB tables?  If not then change this to 0:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=123731968
```

For MyISAM, the most important factor is `key_buffer_size`; it should be no more than about 500M for your case.

What is WHM?

Abrupt stops of mysql (for any reason) leads to the need to `REPAIR` *MyISAM* tables ("marked crashed").  (Consider moving to InnoDB to avoid this recurring nuisance.)

Comment: I wound up reinstalling the server because clients couldn't wait but these are good things to know. It was indeed a memory issue. I had almost no swap for one thing and I suspect cpanel wound up messing up my maria server in an update, causing it to eat up all the RAM. This server had been going for almost 2 years and I hadn't touched it in a long time. Your advice is probably the best anyone could give now that I had to reinstall. Thanks.